# Keeping pages inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am trying to put a website inside an iframe, but this code on the site keeps changing the window of the page. Is there anyway I can get around this? Or better yet, can I disable javascript in an iframe?

```
if(top!=self){
  if(top.location)
    top.location=self.location;
  else
    top.location='http://example.com/not_subframe.html';
}
```

Comment: This would be a tremendous security issue. The code snippet you posted is there for a reason!

Comment: Using weapons or biotechnology also can be security issue. What if author wants to provide just a preview frame? Solution is easily available, just check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, there are several methods of anti-frame busting including disabling JS in a frame (sandboxing, designMode). All described in Limitations of [OWASP:Defending_with_Frame_Breaking_Scripts](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking#Defending_with_Frame_Breaking_Scripts).

Generally use it only with intranet or restricted access site. If you expose site publicly with such tricks you may expect blacklisting by Google or others.

Answer (score 2):

You can only access the content of one frame from within another frame if both frames are from the same domain.

Otherwise this would be an [XSS](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Site_Scripting) issue which is therefore forbidden by a browser.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, can't be done.  Not to mention it's usually a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

Web pages cannot disable JavaScript, if they could, it would be mayhem.

Comment: It is possible with HTML5 sandboxing or designMode attribute.

Answer (score 1):

iFrames have a variety of security features to try to block what you're doing.