# Trying to open a URL in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have two iframes in a HTML page with 50% of the screen shared by both.

In the first iframe http://www.google.com is opened and in the second iframe http://www.nytimes.com is opened.

On Page Load, the page is automatically redirecting to http://www.nytimes.com.

What could be the problem for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out [OWASP - ClickJacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking#Restricted_zones)

Only for Chrome

```
<iframe id="my_frame" sandbox> </iframe>
```

Works great for me ... :)

Answer (score 4):

Most likely, the nytimes.com home page has [framebuster script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framekiller) on it.

Comment: I still need to open nytimes.com in the iframe. Can anything be done for this?

Comment: Then the only reliable way to do this is to proxy the content and strip the framebuster code. (and you'll also need to rewrite the hrefs to go back through your proxy)

Answer (score 2):

Their home page include [this JS file](http://js.nyt.com/js2/build/sitewide/sitewide.js) which contains the following code:

```
(function() {
    if (window.self != window.top && !document.referrer.match(/^https?:\/\/[^?\/]+\.nytimes\.com\//)) {
        var expTime = new Date();
        expTime.setTime(expTime.getTime() + 60000);
        document.cookie = "FramesetReferrer=" + document.referrer + "; expires=" + expTime.toGMTString() + "; path=/";
        top.location.replace(window.location.pathname);
    }
})();
```

This cause the behavior you see.

To protect against this, see the following question here: [Keeping pages inside an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728895/keeping-pages-inside-an-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

Simply because nytimes.com dislike frames and wants to use all of your browserspace.

Why would you ever make a site like that anyway?

Comment: I still need to open nytimes.com in the iframe. Can anything be done for this?

Comment: Not if they are using a framebuster.

Comment: instead of iframe, an overkill solution could be to fetching the html code, parsing the iframe buster out and writing it to the body of your page, kind of a web proxy

Comment: Can framebuster be blocked from our end?

Comment: It cannot be blocked from your end.

Comment: @JosepValls nice idea, but their frame buster code is inside external file that contains all their other JS code as well..

Answer (score 0):

i am guessing that you mean that the iframe container is being redirected. maybe you want to check for some sort of iframe inclusion detection. take a look at: [From the server is there a way to know that my page is being loaded in an Iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732480/from-the-server-is-there-a-way-to-know-that-my-page-is-being-loaded-in-an-iframe)